# ngFor on tr displaying data in the same column

Tags: angular

This is my table component code

```
<table class="table borderless">
  <thead class="thead-dark">
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">Roll No</th>
      <th scope="col">Name</th>
      <th scope="col">Maths</th>
      <th scope="col">Physics</th>
      <th scope="col">Chemistry</th>
      <th scope="col">Biology</th>
      <th scope="col">Total_marks</th>
      <th scope="col">Percentage</th>
      <th scope="col">Division</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let student of students">
      <app-table-item [student]="student"></app-table-item>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

And this is my table-item component code

```
<td>{{student.rollNo}}</td>
<td>{{student.name}}</td>
<td>{{student.maths}}</td>
<td>{{student.physics}}</td>
<td>{{student.chemistry}}</td>
<td>{{student.biology}}</td>
<td>{{student.total}}</td>
<td>{{student.percentage}}%</td>
<td>{{student.division}}</td>
```

The problem is in each iteration after the  a  is getting inserted and then the  elements. Because of this i am getting all those columns in a single columns. Like rollno, name etc are getting displayed under the rollno column itself. Any ideas what can be done here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're generating invalid HTML. `<td>` must be directly under `<tr>`. You may not have an intermediate `<app-table-item>` element.

Quite frankly, if that's all you have in the template of the app-table-item component, this component is probably unnecessary. If you really want to keep it, then change its selector to `[app-table-item]`, and use

```
<tr *ngFor="let student of students" app-table-item [student]="student">
</tr>
```

Comment: Thanks..it worked!...I  know that i don't need another component for that..But still i did it as i need to demonstrate @input directive through this.